Angular 17: Oversized main.js
Upon building my Angular app in production mode, my main.(hash).js is very oversized at around 2.8 mb. Looking at it, it looks like it's integrating all of a third-party library (specifically Kendo) into that file.
Is there a way to split out the kendo library from main.js?
*** Edit
The Kendo modules are used by standalone components, so the component definition will look something like this:
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ButtonModule,
    DropDownsModule,
  ],
  /* other configuration */
})


But the most ideal fix for this, is to enable gzip or brotli (best) so that your main.js is reduced to kilobytes and your application will be ultra fast.
You can reduce the number of kendo imports to only essentials. Kendo has standalone components which you can use to reduce build size, but this involves a lot of rework.
You can also try setting optimization and buildOptimizer to true in angular.json.

The documentation for vendorChuck states that it should only be used for development.

Also, the application is built as a WAR file so it can be service from Tomcat. My servier admins refuse to implement GZIP compression on the server side because we are in a shared instance and a potential impact on performance.

@Jason then you can either rework the kendo modules, to get rid of unused ones, added other recommendations also. But do share the docs, that state vendorChunk should be only for dev, first time I've heard this sorry.

The original link I had to where it stated it in the docs is gone. However, if you look at the schema.json for angular-cli, the message is still there (line 259 as of the time I provided this link):
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/main/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/builders/browser/schema.json

@Jason fine, since its angular docs, would not recommend this change. Then check my updated answer, if its is also done. Then you need to check for unused kendo imports. Also sourcemap should be false, but I guess that is rarely true in prod

we aren't using kendo-all, only the components we need. And sourceMaps are set to false in angular.json.

@Jason wait until someone complains, then recommend enabling compression :) I'm out of ideas sorry :(

yeah, I've got a crazy idea or two about it, but I haven't had time to play with them.

@Jason Usually we can host angular apps in a s3 bucket, that supports compression, but I guess this is a single server with frontend and backend

You're likely suffering from a badly designed app.
To reduce the main bundle size you should rely heavily on lazy loading.
Either by:

Lazy-loading your Module/Standalone components via the router
Lazy loading single components with the @defer block, introduced in v17.


I'm already doing that. The issue is the large size of the kendo library, even though I'm only importing the components in use by the application.

How are you importing it/setting it up ?

The angular components are added "normally", via npm install/ng add. They are specified in the package.json like anything else. The individual routes are specified in the routes file, and loaded via loadComponent: () => import(/* path */).then(/*  */);

I mean the kendo library.

The components in question are standalone, so the Kendo "feature" modules are specified in the component's  imports array. I edited the original question to show the component definition. Also, since the Kendo components are not standalone, I cannot use @defer with them.

It would be interesting to build with NG_BUILD_MANGLE 0 ng build, to check the content of the main.js and confirm that Kendo is at fault.
